# Get year from string format like 1880-01-01T00:00:00.000

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of dates with format like that `1880-01-01T00:00:00.000`. What is the best possible way to get year from this string using javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

Comment: If you come to Stack Overflow for answers to extremely trivial and easily discovered answers, you're going to have a bad time :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse the year from this date string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170117/how-to-parse-the-year-from-this-date-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dateString = "1880-01-01T00:00:00.000";
var date = new Date(dateString);
var year = date.getFullYear();
console.log(year);                  // 1880


// Or simply like:
year = new Date("1880-01-01T00:00:00.000").getFullYear();
console.log(year);                  // 1880


// Interested what methods can you get from the date Object?
// Hit F12 to open developer console and inspect the object
// console.dir( Date.prototype );
// Or directly from the `date` variable:
// console.dir( date.constructor.prototype );
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Also, you can get more than just the year using the [Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) (the variable `date` in @Roko's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the most obvious solution, `'1880-01-01T00:00:00.000'.substr(0,4)`?

Comment: probably because using `Date` you can get `invalid date` but using `.substr` you can get `"pigs"` - so a false-positive.

Comment: Testing for `invalid date` needs nearly the same effort as testing the substring to be a valid number.
If he knows for sure that his dates have that format an additional test isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) just for a part copy of the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) combined date and time string.

```js
var iso6801 = '1880-01-01T00:00:00.000',
    year = iso6801.slice(0, 4);

console.log(year);
```